# Samba - mount - user permission

Tags: linux, share, mount, samba

I am having trouble allowing regular user access samba mount. I can access the mount point as a root, but regular user gets "permission denied" error.

- Server is running on android CM10.1.3, Samba v3.0.20a (Samba Fileshearing app, build: 140525)
- Client is running Fedora 20, Samba client v4.1.6

Here is the mount command:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o credentials=/home/david/.sambacredentials,sec=ntlm,uid=david,gid=david,file_mode=0775,dir_mode=0775 //192.168.1.12/sdcard Documents/
```

Here is the error:

```
$ ls Documents/
ls: cannot open directory Documents/: Permission denied
```

And here are the mount directory permissions:

```
d---rwxr-x. 14 filip filip    0 Jun 26 15:30 Documents/
```

EDIT: smb.conf

```
[global]
interfaces = wlan0
bind interfaces only = yes
workgroup = WORKGROUP
server string = Samba on Android
netbios name = FILIPSMB
remote announce = 255.255.255.255
encrypt passwords = yes
security = USER
restrict anonymous = 1
load printers = no
printcap name = /dev/null
disable spoolss = yes
deadtime = 5
delete readonly = yes
nt acl support = no
inherit permissions = yes
socket options = SO_SNDBUF=16384 SO_RCVBUF=16384
local master = no
unix extensions = yes

[sdcard]
vfs objects = fake_perms
comment = Android /storage/sdcard0
path = /storage/sdcard0
force user = root
read only = no
writable = yes
guest ok = no
```

Comment: Please note that SO is for programming questions. There are other sx sites for admin questions like this. Look around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a common group that contains filip and david. E.g, as root:

```
group add smbusers
groupmod -A david smbusers
groupmod -A filip smbusers
chown filip:smbusers /path/to/Documents
```

The documents group should be:

```
d---rwxr-x. 14 filip smbusers    0 Jun 26 15:30 Documents/
```

I do NOT recommend permissions of 0075 for Documents, so why not

```
chmod 0775 /path/to/Documents
```

The documents group will now be:

```
drwxrwxr-x. 14 filip smbusers    0 Jun 26 15:30 Documents/
```

Now try reconnecting as user. (you can also add a list of `valid users` for the share in `smb.conf`, but for now, let's get the directory and groups in a sane configuration.)

You must also have `Documents` be a valid samba share (sorry, I presumed you had already done this). In `smb.conf`, create a `Documents` share (the name can be anything you like). It will look similar to this based on your previous posting)

```
[Documents]
        comment = Documents Share
        path = /full/path/to/Documents
        valid users = smbusers # the group you created holding david & filip
        browseable = Yes
        writeable = Yes
```

After editing smb.conf, run `testparm` which will check for errors and provide a dump of your shares. Then restart samba (both smb and nmb daemons). Confirm that `david` has access to the `Documents` share with:

```
smbclient -Udavid -Llocalhost
```

Then try to reconnect to Documents. (if you experience any problems with the `smbclient` command, then substitute your actual hostname for localhost. (that will indicate a failure in wins resolution, to correct, add the following to the global section of smb.conf:

```
 name resolve order = lmhosts wins host bcast
```